# Refactor Angular 17 - Query Builder - to remove nested call - Use NgTemplate

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code, that builds query but I want to avoid the duplicate code, i.e. app.component.ts is calling query-builder, and also query-builder.component.ts is also calling query-builder.

`app.component.html`:

Code:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="QueryBuilderCtrl">
    <h1>Angular.js Query Builder</h1>

    <div class="alert alert-info">
      <strong>Example Output</strong><br>
      <span [innerHTML]="output"></span>
    </div>

    <query-builder [group]="filter.group"></query-builder>
  </div>
</div>
```

`app.component.ts`

Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Group, QueryService } from './shared/query.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  filter: any;
  output: string = '';

  constructor(private queryService: QueryService) {
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const data = '{"group": {"operator": "AND","rules": []}}';
    this.filter = JSON.parse(data);
  }

  onQueryChanged(group: Group) {
    this.output = this.queryService.computed(group);
  }
}
```

`query-builder.component.ts`

Code:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Group, QueryService, Rule } from '../shared/query.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'query-builder',
  templateUrl: './query-builder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./query-builder.component.css']
})
export class QueryBuilderComponent {
  @Input() group: Group = { operator: 'AND', rules: [] };
  operators = [{
    name: 'AND'
  }, {
    name: 'OR'
  }];;
  fields = [{
    name: 'Firstname'
  }, {
    name: 'Lastname'
  }, {
    name: 'Birthdate'
  }, {
    name: 'City'
  }, {
    name: 'Country'
  }];;
  conditions = [{
    name: '='
  }, {
    name: '<>'
  }, {
    name: '<'
  }, {
    name: '<='
  }, {
    name: '>'
  }, {
    name: '>='
  }];
  @Output() queryChanged = new EventEmitter<Group>();

  constructor(private queryService: QueryService) {
    
   }

  addCondition() {
    this.group.rules.push({ field: '', condition: '', data: '' });
    this.queryChanged.emit(this.group);
  }

  addGroup() {
    this.group.rules.push({ group: { operator: 'AND', rules: [] } });
    this.queryChanged.emit(this.group);
  }

  removeGroup() {
    const parent = this.group.parent;
    if (parent) {
      // TODO TO BE FINALISED
      // parent.rules.splice(index, 1);
      this.queryChanged.emit(parent);
    }
  }

  removeCondition(rule: Rule) {
    // this.group.rules.splice(index, 1);
    this.queryChanged.emit(this.group);
  }
}
```

`query-builder.component.html`

Code:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <select [(ngModel)]="group.operator" class="form-control input-sm">
            <option *ngFor="let o of operators" [value]="o.name">{{ o.name }}</option>
        </select>
        <button style="margin-left: 5px" (click)="addCondition()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Condition</button>
        <button style="margin-left: 5px" (click)="addGroup()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Group</button>
        <button style="margin-left: 5px" (click)="removeGroup()" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span> Remove Group</button>
    </div>
    <div class="group-conditions">
        <div *ngFor="let rule of group.rules" class="condition">
            <div [ngSwitch]="rule.hasOwnProperty('group')">
                <div *ngSwitchCase="true">
                    <query-builder [group]="rule.group"></query-builder>
                </div>
                <div *ngSwitchDefault>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <select [(ngModel)]="rule.field" class="form-control input-sm">
                            <option *ngFor="let t of fields" [value]="t.name">{{ t.name }}</option>
                        </select>
                        <select style="margin-left: 5px" [(ngModel)]="rule.condition" class="form-control input-sm">
                            <option *ngFor="let c of conditions" [value]="c.name">{{ c.name }}</option>
                        </select>
                        <input style="margin-left: 5px" type="text" [(ngModel)]="rule.data"
                            class="form-control input-sm" />
                        <button style="margin-left: 5px" (click)="removeCondition(rule)"
                            class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign">Delete</span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Full Code is here: https://github.com/shah-smit/angular-expression-builder